# Passing unicode string to templatetag in django template cause the error

Tags: django, django-templates

I use mezzanine to build my site. In template I use templatetag. When I pass to this templatetag word like "categorytofilter", it's ok, but when I try to pass unicode string:

```
{% blog_recent_posts limit=6 category='Статьи' as recent_posts %}
```

I see the error:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 10-15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I fix it? TIA!

Comment: Does this help any? I'm not sure specifically what the answer is, but I figured the link would help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#templates

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're passing the category as ascii, not unicode.

Try

```
{% blog_recent_posts limit=6 category=u'Статьи' as recent_posts %}
```

if you're hardcoding the category, otherwise, specify/cast it in your view before passing to the template.